# Numeric Representations Without Machine Primitives

Tags: types, numbers

**Synopsis**

Post examples in any language of a type that represents integers without making direct use of machine integers. Include mappings *to* and *from* the user-defined type. Points for efficiency in space and/or time.

**Original Question**

In the comments of [a certain rather bold answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137217/in-what-situations-is-an-oop-design-approach-suboptimal/3137271#3137271) to a question about object-oriented programming, I stated my belief that machine primitives are not objects, but was unable to really substantiate that claim, in the same way that the poster of that answer was unable to substantiate his claims about the universality and fundamental nature of object-oriented philosophy.

So that got me to thinking. In C++, a language in which machine primitives do not participate in the class hierarchy, is it possible to define an object type—say, `Integer`—that does *not* make use of a machine primitive to store its value?

There is [this beautiful bit of template hackery](http://nonchalantlytyped.net/blog/2010/04/24/church-numerals-in-c/) that implements Church numerals. Unfortunately, since the conversions between whole numbers and Church numerals occurs strictly at compile time, there's no way to get around using machine integers for, say, user input.

So what I'm looking for is a *runtime* equivalent of the above, though not necessarily using Church numerals, with reasonable space requirements, that can be implemented in a language such as C++ without higher-order functions. I'd like to see examples in other languages, as well, especially those that make use of fun dynamic typing tricks. Pointers and function pointers shall not count as primitives as long as the stored address is used strictly as such and not for its integral value.

Bonus points for accommodating all integers (i.e., not just whole numbers), and super bonus points for devising a system in which floating-point numbers can also be implemented.

To avoid any unpleasantness down the line, and to encourage polite discussion, I'm making this a community wiki question from the start.

Comment: what the hell do you want to do ? Ultimately all boils down to machine integers.

Comment: You can encode naturals as lists (or vectors etc) of any element type. Empty list is zero, addition is concatenation. Are you looking for something more sophisticated than this?

Comment: *"Bonus points for accommodating all integers (i.e., not just whole numbers)"* -- huh ?

Comment: @Alexandre, I'm pretty sure that the idea is just to have fun.

Comment: @Alexandre: Either I spark a really interesting discussion about alternate numeric representations, or I show that it all boils down to machine integers no matter which way you look at it and object-oriented programming is a *philosophy* that corresponds to computers no better or worse than functional programming.

Comment: @Paul: Church numerals encode only the set whole numbers, {0, 1, 2, ...}. Integers can be negative: {..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...}.

Comment: @Jon: That's a good, simple method. I'm looking for any interesting solution to the problem.

Comment: @Jon: -ve numbers are enumerable, i.e. they can be mapped onto naturals, so they can be church-encoded.

Comment: @Jon Purdy: ah - when you say "whole numbers" you mean positive integers ?

Comment: @jon: Good point, thanks. @Paul: Nonnegative integers, yes, though apparently opinions vary as to the correct definition.

Comment: @Jon: Church numerals can be generalized to represent negative numbers: see http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lambda-calc-opposites.txt & http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/lambda-arithm-neg.scm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here a class that can be used for positive integers. and could easily be extended to account for negatives as well.
it supports addition, subtraction, equality, inequality and multiplication. Division can be implmented based on the existing operators. So all in all I'd say it pretty much represents integers and there's no use of any simple types. Actually the only type the class uses is it self.

The implementation is basically a link list with some optimization so that traversing of the list ain't needed for every operation.

```
public class MyInt
    {
        private MyInt _previous;
        private MyInt _first;
        private bool isEven;

        private MyInt(MyInt previous)
        {
            next++;
            _previous = previous;
            isEven = previous == null ? true : !previous.isEven;
            getFirst();
            x = next;
        }

        private void getFirst()
        {
            if (_previous == null)
                _first = null;
            else if (_previous._first == null)
                _first = this;
            else
                _first = _previous._first;
        }

        private MyInt(MyInt copy, bool dontuse)
        {
            _previous = copy._previous == null ? null : new MyInt(copy._previous,true);
            getFirst();
            x = copy.x;
        }

        public static MyInt operator +(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs))
                rhs = new MyInt(rhs, true);
            if (lhs == MyInt.Zero)
                return rhs;
            if (rhs == MyInt.Zero)
                return lhs;
            else
            {
                var isEven = rhs.isEven == lhs.isEven;
                var result = new MyInt(rhs, true);
                result._first._previous = lhs;
                result._first = lhs._first;
                result.isEven = isEven;
                return result;
            }
        }

        public static MyInt operator -(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
        {
            if (lhs == rhs)
                return MyInt.Zero;
            if (rhs == MyInt.Zero)
                return lhs;
            if (lhs == MyInt.Zero)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Negatives not supported");
            else
            {
                return lhs._previous - rhs._previous;
            }
        }

        public static MyInt operator --(MyInt un)
        {
            if (un == MyInt.Zero)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Negatives not supported");
            return un._previous;
        }

        public static MyInt operator *(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
        {
            if (lhs == MyInt.Zero || rhs == MyInt.Zero)
                return MyInt.Zero;

            var temp = lhs;
            var one = One;
            var two = one + one;
            var zero = MyInt.Zero;
            var dbl = lhs + lhs;
            if (rhs == MyInt.One)
                return lhs;
            if (rhs == two)
                return dbl;
            for (MyInt times = rhs + one; times._previous._previous != zero && times._previous != zero; times = times-two)
            {
                temp = temp + dbl;
            }
            if (rhs.isEven)
                temp = temp - lhs;
            return temp;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) && object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null))
                return true;
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(rhs, null)))
                return false;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(lhs._previous, null) && object.ReferenceEquals(rhs._previous, null))
                return true;
            if ((object.ReferenceEquals(lhs._previous, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(rhs._previous, null)))
                return false;

            return (lhs._previous == rhs._previous);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(MyInt lhs, MyInt rhs)
        {
            return !(lhs == rhs);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is MyInt && ((MyInt)obj) == this;
        }

        public static MyInt Zero
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyInt(null);
            }
        }

        public static MyInt One
        {
            get
            {
                return new MyInt(new MyInt(null));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a very interesting take on a list-based implementation! I also think `bool` is fine here, since it'd be trivially implemented in terms of referential types (null for false, non-null for true).

Comment: basically the bool is just me being lazy. I needed a copy constructor but since I already had a constructor taking MyInt I needed a differrent signature (yes I know it's not pretty :) )

Comment: Do'h you ment isEven of course and yes that could be implemented as null/not null or simply ommitted. It's an optimization for the multiplication operator

Answer (score 1):

There's always Lisp, in which 0 can be represented as `()` (the empty list), 1 is `(())`, 2 is `(() ())`, etc. This was proved way back in the day, but of course no Lisp implementation actually uses that, as it's too slow to believe.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the set-theoretic definition of natural numbers.